# Put new lines to JSON for my markers (Leaflet)

Tags: json, leaflet

I'm putting up markers on my map and I want my marker to have something like this when you click the markers on the map.

```
FirstLine
SecondLine
```

I currently have a markers.json

```
markers = [
{
    "name": "FirstLine \n SecondLine",
    "lat": 30.1234,
    "lng": -97.2345
    }
];
```

However that doesn't work for me, I still get one really long line instead of SecondLine beginning at another line.

I'm using Leaflet and I have a markers.json that have all of my data.

EDIT: I have a js file that's using popup to generate the markers.

```
for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ) 
{
   L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng] )
  .bindPopup( '<a target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>' )
  .addTo( map );
}
```

Comment: Could you supply the code which you use to create the markers? Now we can't see what you are using to display the text. Popup? Label?

Comment: Sorry. It's popup, I've edited my question above.
Wait, I think I need to add a "\n" in my for loop. How would I make it so that .bindPopup would know which one is FirstLine and SecondLine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it. I realized you just add < br > in the js file when I'm generating my markers.

Comment: :) I've also added an answer for the people who aren't able to convert their source data and need to do it on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Leaflet's popup does accept HTML `<br>` linebreaks so if you first convert your string before adding it to the popup you should be ok:

```
for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ) {
    var newName = markers[i].name.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng] )
        .bindPopup( '<a target="_blank">' + newName + '</a>' )
        .addTo( map );
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qk7aUn?p=preview